# Market clearing price and dual variables in auctions

Tags: mathematical-economics, price, auctions, linear-programming

Suppose the allocation of an auction (or a market) is defined by the solution of a linear program.

Then it is known that the associated clearing price is given by the dual variable associated to the offer-equals-demand constraint, see for example [slide 19 of this course on electricity markets](http://pierrepinson.com/31761/Lectures/31761-Lecture1.pdf).

It is also known that when duality is not well defined (for example in the presence of non-convexities, such as in mixed integer programs), finding clearing prices might be difficult, as explained in O'neil et. al. *Efficient market-clearing prices in markets with nonconvexities* (2005).

I am sure there is a simple answer to my question but here it is: in an auction, why use the dual to find a clearing price instead of simply setting as a clearing price the highest accepted offer (that is the highest price amongst bids that receive a positive allocation)?